# How to get follower and following count quickly with Firebase and Swift

Tags: swift, firebase

I am currently trying to fetch all the followers for a specific user with firebase. In my didSet clause, I call the function setFollowingCount() to fetch the users that the current user follows and assign it to a text field:

```
 var user: User? {
    didSet {

        setFollowingCount()
        guard let following = self.user?.following else {return}
        let attributedText = NSMutableAttributedString(string: "\(following)\n", attributes: [NSAttributedStringKey.font: UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 14)])

        attributedText.append(NSAttributedString(string: "followers", attributes: [NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor: UIColor.lightGray, NSAttributedStringKey.font: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 14)]))

        self.followingLabel.attributedText = attributedText

    }
}
```

The setFollowingCount() function is:

```
func setFollowingCount(){
    var i = 0
    guard let userId = self.user?.uid else { return }
    Database.database().reference().child("following").child(userId).observe(.value) { (snapshot) in
          self.user?.following = Int(snapshot.childrenCount)
    }

}
```

The problem is that this takes very long to load and often freezes the entire app when you look at a user's profile. How can I speed this up or make it work more efficiently?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
self.user?.following = Int(snapshot.childrenCount)
```

Is not an efficient solution. `.childrenCount` actually loops over the snapshot and counts all of the children which is going to be slow.

Instead you want to store the number of followers as a single value you can retrieve it faster.

```
following: {
    uid: {
        followingCount: 100,
        follwersCount: 150
    }
}
```

Then you can query like this:

```
Database.database().reference().child("following").child(userId).observeSingleEvent(of: .value) { (snapshot) in
        if let counts = snap.value as? [String: AnyObject] }
            let followingCount = counts["followingCount"] as? Int
            let followersCount = counts["followersCount"] as? Int

            // save these values somewhere
        }       
    })
```

I would also recommend you increment / decrement the follower counts in a transaction block so the count doesn't get messed up. That can look something like this:

```
static func incrementCount(countName: String) {
    if let uid = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid {
        let databaseReference = Database.database().reference()
        databaseReference.child("following").child(uid).runTransactionBlock { (currentData: MutableData) -> TransactionResult in
            if var data = currentData.value as? [String: Any] {
                var count = data[countName] as! Int
                count += 1
                data[countName] = count
                currentData.value = data
                return TransactionResult.success(withValue: currentData)
            }
        return TransactionResult.success(withValue: currentData)
        }
    }        
}
```

Lastly,
If you're going to use `.observe` you need to remove the reference. In this case though you aren't looking for updates so you can use `.observeSingleEvent`